# How to make spring batch step execution parallel with configurable thread count?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am having following spring-batch application

SpringBatchApplication.java

```
package com.spbt.job.sample;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBatchApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBatchApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

TraverseJob.java

```
package com.spbt.job.sample;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class TraverseJob {

    @Autowired
    protected JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    protected StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    private String inputFolderPath = "/tmp/inputFolder";

    @Bean("TraverseJob")
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("TraverseJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(traverseStep())
                .build();
    }


    @Bean("TraverseStep")
    public Step traverseStep() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("TraverseStep")
                .tasklet(traverseJobTasklet(null))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean("TraverseJobTasklet")
    @StepScope
    public TraverseJobTasklet traverseJobTasklet(@Value("#{jobParameters[date]}") String date) {
        TraverseJobTasklet tasklet = new TraverseJobTasklet();

        tasklet.setJobDate(date);
        tasklet.setJobDirPath(inputFolderPath);

        return tasklet;
    }
}
```

TraverseJobTasklet.java

```
package com.spbt.job.sample;

import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import java.io.File;

public class TraverseJobTasklet implements Tasklet {

    private String jobDirPath;
    private String jobDate;

    @Autowired
    private RemoteFilePush remoteFilePush;

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        try {
            traverseDir(new File(jobDirPath));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }

    private void traverseDir(File filePath) throws Exception {
        try {
            File[] files = filePath.listFiles();
            if (files != null) {
                for (File file : files) {
                    String name = file.getName();
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        if (remoteFilePush.isRemoteDirExist(name)) {
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            remoteFilePush.createRemoteDir(name);
                            traverseDir(file);
                        }
                    } else {
                        remoteFilePush.pushFile(file.getPath());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception("empty/null dir -> " + filePath.getName());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }


    public String getJobDirPath() {
        return jobDirPath;
    }

    public void setJobDirPath(String jobDirPath) {
        this.jobDirPath = jobDirPath;
    }

    public String getJobDate() {
        return jobDate;
    }

    public void setJobDate(String jobDate) {
        this.jobDate = jobDate;
    }
}
```

RemoteFilePushLogic.java

```
package com.spbt.job.sample;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class RemoteFilePush {

    public boolean isRemoteDirExist(String name) throws InterruptedException {
        boolean isRemoteDirExist = false;
        // code to check dir on remote server
        return isRemoteDirExist;
    }

    public void createRemoteDir(String name) throws InterruptedException {
        // code to create dir on remote server
    }

    public void pushFile(String path) throws InterruptedException {
        // code to push file on remote server
        System.out.println("Pushed");
    }
}
```

I want to do parallel traversal and execution in traverseDir method in TraverseJobTasklet, by keeping my RemoteFilePush Logic intact, my inputFolderPath can contain multiple child directories each of which contains some files in it.

I have tried to follow [link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/3.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/scalability.html#scalabilityParallelSteps) for spring-batch version which I am using, But its xml based and I do not seem to get how can I create multiple step out of single traverseStep I have?

Comment: `my inputFolderPath can contain multiple child directories each of which contains some files in it.`: Have you tried a partitioned step where each partition is a sub-folder to traverse?

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine I was trying to do ItemReader<File> and ItemWriter I am not able to set the directory looping in Reader/Writer Step, Having said that, I haven't tried Partitioned Step.

Comment: In my use case I do not want to open and read file line by line, I just want to upload the fileBytes to remote server using HTTP call.

Comment: A partitioned step does not have to be a chunk-oriented step. The worker step could be a simple tasklet. It's only its input that will be a subset of the initial dataset (in your case, a sub-folder per worker step).

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine correct, input a sub-folder string path per worker step is where i am hitting wall with spring code, if you can point me to some ref. it will be helpful, most of the example on net is xml based.

Comment: I added a quick sample with Java config. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> input a sub-folder string path per worker step is where i am hitting wall with spring code, if you can point me to some ref. it will be helpful, most of the example on net is xml based.

Here is a quick self-contained example with Java config:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.Partitioner;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class PartitionJobSample {

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobs;
    private final StepBuilderFactory steps;

    public PartitionJobSample(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        this.jobs = jobs;
        this.steps = steps;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step managerStep() {
        return steps.get("masterStep")
                .partitioner(workerStep().getName(), partitioner(null))
                .step(workerStep())
                .gridSize(4)
                .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();// TODO useful for testing, use a more robust task executor in production
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Partitioner partitioner(@Value("#{jobParameters['rootFolder']}") String rootFolder) {
        List<String> subFolders = getSubFolders(rootFolder);
        return new Partitioner() {
            @Override
            public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
                Map<String, ExecutionContext> map = new HashMap<>(gridSize);
                for (String folder : subFolders) {
                    ExecutionContext executionContext = new ExecutionContext();
                    executionContext.put("filePath", folder);
                    map.put("partition-for-" + folder, executionContext);
                }
                return map;
            }
        };
    }

    private List<String> getSubFolders(String rootFolder) {
        // TODO implement this
        return Arrays.asList("/data/folder1", "/data/folder2");
    }

    @Bean
    public Step workerStep() {
        return steps.get("workerStep")
                .tasklet(getTasklet(null))
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public Tasklet getTasklet(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['filePath']}") String filePath) {
        return new TraverseJobTasklet(filePath);
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(managerStep())
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(PartitionJobSample.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("rootFolder", "/data")
                .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    }

    class TraverseJobTasklet implements Tasklet {

        private String filePath;

        public TraverseJobTasklet(String filePath) {
            this.filePath = filePath;
        }

        @Override
        public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
            // TODO call traversePath for filePath which is a sub-folder here
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " processing sub-folder " + filePath);
            return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        }
    }

}
```

It passes the root directory as a job parameter and executes a partitioned step where each worker processes a sub-folder (calling your tasklet).

If you run it, you should see something like:

```
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2 processing sub-folder /data/folder1
SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 processing sub-folder /data/folder2
```

I will let you adapt it to your situation accordingly.

Comment: Thanks  Mahmoud Ben Hassine for facade for my reference

Comment: @ Mahmoud Ben Hassine For AsyncTaskExecutor What do you mean by "useful for testing, use a more robust task executor in production" can you please elaborate?

Comment: `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` does not reuse threads (see its javadoc). If you have a lot of partitions, you will have as many threads as partitions (which might not be what you want). A pooled task executor is better in terms of resource utilisation (for example use the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`, but remember to shut it down after you job).

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud, I am able to use ThreadPoolTaskExecuter (TPTE) , One more doubt is about exception handling
How can we gracefully Exit the step and job on exception during execution-failure of one of the Tasklet based Tasks (spawned by TPTE)